# NetworkManager dispatcher script

Tags: sh, x11

scripts in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d will got exec and parameters will be passed to the scripts by NetworkManager.

One of my laptop BIOS is malfunctioning, I have to manually sync the time, and do system upgrade BTW. I am working with a script to automate this task.
Here's the script:
    #!/bin/sh

```
IF=$1
STATUS=$2

if [ "$STATUS"x != 'up'x -o "$(date +%Y)" -gt "2012"  ] ;then
   exit
fi

logger  "==$0=="
wait_for_process(){
    PNAME=$1
    PID=`pgrep $PNAME`
    while [ -z "$PID" ];do
        logger "waiting $1 running for another 3 sec.."
        sleep 3;
        PID=`pgrep $PNAME`
    done
    logger "$1 is running!"
}
wait_for_process nm-applet
wait_for_process lxpanel

export DISPLAY=$(echo $DISPLAY | cut -c -2)

if [ -z $DISPLAY ];then
    export DISPLAY=:0
fi

#below cmd will yield null string for $user
user=$(who | grep "$DISPLAY" | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n1)
#so I have to hardcode the user name:(
user=xxx
export XAUTHORITY="/home/$user/.Xauthority"

logger "Display $DISPLAY user $user"

su $user -c "xterm -e 'sudo /usr/bin/ntpd -qdg && sudo yaourt -Syua' &" || logger "cannot run xterm"
```

(the script is invoked before x window, run as root)

`user=$(who | grep "$DISPLAY" | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n1)` cannot find the login user name. But it works in xterm.
Can someone help?

I am using archlinux i686 + openbox + lxpanel

edit:
I want to find the real login user name, while the script is run by root.

Comment: A lot of confusion and missing a real use case. On one hand, you seem to want to get a list of (active) user sessions, on the other hand, you seem to expect it to work *before* the session(s) are started, which is just nonsense. Not much to help here unless the question is modified to make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the name of the user running the script?  How about:

```
user=$( id -un )
```

Comment: The user that runs the script is root.  I want to find the login user name